# How can I cool down if my air conditioner isn't operating properly?

Tags: air, repair

My air conditioner continues to turn off by itself since it's so hot outside. I currently take cold showers, drink lots of water, and other things in order to not pass out. What else should I do?

Comment: Clean the AC. If the coil gets dirty, condensation can collect and freeze on the coil. The system works harder to thaw the coil, but shuts off quickly due to overheating. Refrigerant Problems: Low refrigerant is also a common cause of a frozen evaporator coil. Visit https://www.arlinghausair.com/why-does-my-air-conditioner-keep-turning-off-too-quickly/

Comment: Your air conditioner should not turn itself off due to excessive heat. If anything, it should work so long as the exhaust is hotter than the air temperature and the coils are clean and the airflow is free to flow around the coils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to cool down your body temperature. 
Some of them technical and some others just basic life hacks like wearing proper clothes.

But first keep in mind the golden rule : Cold air always prefer to flow  downward while hot air flow upward.So if you try to cool a place do not try to flow cold air from the top , hot air will heat the cold air and you will not succeed cold the room. Also opening a small hatch in room's ceiling will help hot air to flow away. So having "wasistas windows" will help a lot.

A Technical Cool Tip :
Technically you can use Ventilators to cool down the room; all you need is a ventilator and ices cubes hanged behind it so cold air can flow in room.

A Basic Life Hack Tip :
Always wear 100% COTTON clothes it will help you to balance your body temperature. And joints, armpits, elbows,nape and back of the knees are the most open places for your vessels .If you use and cold things like frozen bottles on them will help you to feel cold fast then any part of your body.
But aware of cold burn!

For your health always be sure the temperature difference between outside and inside should not be more than 6-8 degrees.

I hope these little informations helps.

Comment: I find that pure wool (not a blend) is much cooler than cotton. Wool can wick moisture away from your body that cotton does not. Wool socks, for example, keep your feet warm and dry where cotton does not. Excess humidity is worse than dry heat as evaporation to keep you cool is not so efficient.